# My Windows DOS setup appears to be corrupt in ways that I don't understand

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

My Windows DOS setup appears to be corrupt in ways that I don't understand:

CD environmental variable only work when launching a `cmd` with the option `/C` or `/K`, meanwhile if I use a batch (which is my goal) or a standard cmd page it does not work.

In addition to this behaviour, I also have a problem with the `start` command: even though my path is correct, and file is there, whenever I use the `/max` or `/wait` option the result is `program.exe` is not found, meanwhile if I don't use any argument it launches normally. E.G. `start "" /d "C:\Program_1.0\" /max /wait "Program1.0.exe"` results in the program not being found.

What might cause these issues? I'm going crazy over here.

@ramhound you're talking about the `PATH` variable, I'm talking about the `!CD!` variable of the MS DOS.

As example:

```
@echo off
REM : ------------------------------------------------------------------
REM : main
chcp 1252
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@echo CURRENTDIR=!CD!

REM : parent directory of script
pushd "%~dp0" >NUL && set "WORKINGDIR="!CD!"" && popd >NUL

@echo WORKINGDIR=!WORKINGDIR!
pause
```

Here `currentdir` and `workingdir` will have the same output whatever location I use to launch this script.

@DavidPostill:

Thank you, you're right: when executing the script from the windows explorer - or if you launch the batch file in a console navigating to its parent folder - the script DOS doesn't change the working directory. But the system MUST do it when calling the script from elsewhere (such as using its full path from the default console under %USERPROFILE%). And that is precisely my first issue: for me it's not the case. Try yourself and you'll have CURRENTDIR = %USERPROFILE%, WORKINGDIR = parent_folder of the batch file. And when calling from %USERPROFILE% with cmd /C instead of directly the batch file, it works. It almost looks like if the delayed expansion isn't working, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Your command prompt isn't corrupt.  Something else which has a simple solution is going on, but what that is exactly, cannot be determined by the information provided.  You are aware there are two system variables, one for the entire system, one just for the user.

Comment: Yes, I do, but with CD variable I mean the cd variable that you use in a batch, like CURRENTPATH=%CD%.

Comment: Irrelevant tags removed.

Comment: Even after removing the `cd ..` from my script and opening a new console then calling my script using it's full name works as expected. I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Note: What you are pushing is `~dp0` which is the script directory - not the script parent directory as you seem to think it is in your `rem`.

Comment: You're right, it is the directory of my script that I defined as "WORKINGDIR". Anyways, oddly enough, every other pc that I have tried had different versions of windows 10 and different hardware, but in every other one worked. In my current pc (Windows 10 Pro + chcp 850) it doesn't work in any way other than with cmd /c. I really don't get what's going on here. It's also the youngest of my many windows installations.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here `currentdir` and `workingdir` will have the same output whatever location I use to launch this script.

Your script **doesn't actually change the directory**. So the 2 values being the same is not surprising.

You are pushing `%~dp0` which is the current directory of the script ...

The following batch file demonstrates what happens if you actually change  the directory to the parent of the script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo CURRENTDIR=!CD!
echo ~dp0=%~dp0%
rem save current directory, change to the parent directory, store the name of the parent directory
pushd "%~dp0" >NUL && cd .. && set "WORKINGDIR="!CD!"" && popd >NUL
echo WORKINGDIR=!WORKINGDIR!
echo CURRENTDIR=!CD!
pause
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The directory change is only valid between the `push` and `pop` commands.
- `%WORKINGDIR%` is now different because of the preceding `cd ..` which changes the current directory.
- CURRENTDIR doesn't change because it is used outside of the `push`/pop`pairing and the current directory is restored by`popd`

Output:

```
> test
CURRENTDIR=F:\test
~dp0=F:\test\
WORKINGDIR="F:\"
CURRENTDIR=F:\test
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [Pushd - change directory/folder - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- [Popd - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [Windows Environment Variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: edited to reply